# error while trying to create product attributes from magento backend

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

`I am getting error while trying to create any product attribute.`

This is the error i am getting. I have nothing else to share.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`kingshop`.`eav_attribute_label`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_LABEL_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attributex`
>   (`attribute_id`) ON DEL)

N.B -> `I have checked the Engines. All EAV tables are using INNODB engines.`

&& `This error is showing while trying to create attribute from magento backend. No frontend installer.`

Comment: put your attribute installer

Comment: check the question carefully..i am not using any frontend installer.

Comment: probably it means that attribute with such label already exists in your eav. Have you tried add attribute with another label?

Comment: its throwing error whenever i am going to create attribute. And there was no attribute created before like that name/code

Comment: do one thing .Please take the backup of the eav_attribute_label table and the truncate that table..Hope its help..

Comment: are you kidding?..magento will run after i truncate the table?