# Magento display products list outside magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Hello i'm trying to embed some magento functions in a static page outside the framework.
Everything is working except when i try to use the magento standard output for list of products.

As i said before i want to use the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List with the template in catalog/product/list.phtml.

The code is:

```
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$layout = Mage::app('default')->setCurrentStore( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
->getLayout();
$layout->getUpdate()
->addHandle('default')
->load();
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();
$head=$layout->getBlock('head');
echo $head->toHtml();

<!-- NOW THE LIST BLOCK -->

$categoryid = 3;
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$_productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$toolbar=new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar();
$toolbar->setCollection($_productCollection);
$list_block=new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List();
$list_block->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
$list_block->setCollection($_productCollection);



?>
<pre><?php echo $list_block->toHtml();?></pre>
```

I have this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function createBlock() on a non-object in /webprod/sites/private/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php on line 183
```

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears because you are creating an instance of the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` class using `new`. You should use the `createBlock` method because some other stuff happens in there. Also I don't think you need to create an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` block. This should happen automatically (on the same line where you get the error).

While you are at it, don't create an instance of the category model like that either. Use `Mage::getModel()`.
And I don't think that calling `setCollection` on the list block will work. Try setting the category id.
So your code shold become:

```
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$layout = Mage::app('default')->setCurrentStore( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
->getLayout();
$layout->getUpdate()
->addHandle('default')
->load();
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();
$head=$layout->getBlock('head');
echo $head->toHtml();

<!-- NOW THE LIST BLOCK -->

$categoryid = 3;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->load($categoryid);

$list_block= Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list');
$list_block->setCategoryId($categoryid)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');

?>
<pre><?php echo $list_block->toHtml();?></pre>
```

Comment: I'm not getting the error but i can't display products anyway. Maybe ->toHtml() it is not working in this way. Should i use renderView()? 
Thanks

Comment: hmm...strange. toHtml should work just fine. I've edited the answer and added a template to the block. Maybe that was it.

Comment: Working perfect :)
It was missing the template.!

Comment: @Marius can you please trying to answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334738/error-while-trying-to-create-product-attributes-from-magento-backend that will really helpful

Comment: @KingshukDeb. I saw the question already. Sorry but I have no idea and I cannot reproduce it. Try to follow the recommendations from here. maybe you get a result: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/146

Comment: Thanks for checking..but do you really think its a php error??..i can debug only php errors. How can i debug mysql error??..If its showing in custom module then i can do something. But its showing in magento default features. Do know what to do. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @KingshukDeb. This does not reproduce in a vanilla install. Maybe it's a custom module that screws things up. Try disabling them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

    $cat_id = 56;
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
        $collection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position');
        //$catcount = $collection->count();
        Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
foreach ($collection as $product) {
echo $product->getName();
echo $product->getPrice();
echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(260);
echo $product->getProductUrl();
?>

Please use that code working fine.
```